# Double sum of Lambert series: Partial sum in closed form desired!

Tags: sequences-and-series, theta-functions, q-series, q-analogs

We desire the things stated in the title for:

$\sum_{k=2}^m \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} {q^n\over {1-q^n}}$

Some things I've looked into that may be of some help:

The first sum is just a truncated (partially summed) Lambert series, so take a look at the truncated Lambert series.

[Answer #2 from this other question, which may be able to help using theta functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60311/infinite-series-of-the-form-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1ak1)

[If you're going to jump into using Mathematica or Sage, check out the q-polygamma functions, specifically q-digamma](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24902240?read-now=1&seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents)

[More on the q-digamma function, check out Wolfram Alpha's entry too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Comment: There are some interesting expansions towards this end in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03488.pdf).